# Sending query data in a node http.request

Tags: node.js, http, http-post

Here is my situation. Before my server renders a page, it needs to make an API call in order to retrieve metadata that it will insert into the page.

From http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

I am using the vanilla node method `http.request`

Here is my code so far:

```
    var options = {
        host: 'otogodirect.ca',
        port: 8080,
        path: '/api/vehicleView',
        method: 'POST'
    };
    var vehicleView = http.request(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.log('error');
    });
    vehicleView.write('userName=nico');
    vehicleView.end();
```

In the second to last line I am trying to pass userName=nico as query parameter in my post request. However it doesn't look like it's coming through to the API. My question: how can I pass an object such as

```
{userName: 'nico', id: 123332}
```

to my API call.

**Warning** I have seen similar questions on SO, however all of the answers use some third-party node package (i.e. request, requestify). I will probably use one in the future but for now I want it to work in **PURE VANILLA NODE** so that I can understand exactly how it works, so please **NO ANSWERS WITH 3rd PARTY NODE PACKAGES** Thank you.

Comment: I also would like to know

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your entire problem, but converting from a JSON object to a querystring and back again can be done with the [querystring module](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) in Node core.